# Nested SQL call

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

EDIT:

As requested, our table schema is,

**posts**:

- `postid` (primary key),
- `post_text`

**comments**:

- `commentid` (primary key) ,
- `postid` (foreign key referencing **posts**.`postid`),
- `comment_text`

**replies**

- `replyid` (primary key)
- `commentid` (foreign key referencing **comments**.commentid)
- `reply_text`

---

I have the tables **posts**, **comments**, and **replies** in a SQL database. (Obviously, a post can have comments, and a comment can have replies)

I want to return a post based on its id, `postid`.

So I would like a database function has the inputs and outputs,

#### input:

`postid`

#### output:

```
post = {
    postid
    post_text
    
    comments: [comment, ...]
}
```

Where the comment and reply are nested in the post,

```
comment = {
    commentid, 
    text
    
    replies: [reply, ...]

}
```

```
reply = {
    replyid
    reply_text
}
```

I have tried using joins, but the returned data is highly redundant, and it seems stupid. For instance, fetching the data from two different replies will give,

| postid | post_text | commentid | comment_text | replyid | reply_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | POST_TEXT | 78 | COMMENT_TEXT | 14 | REPLY1_TEXT |
| 1 | POST_TEXT | 78 | COMMENT_TEXT | 15 | REPLY2_TEXT |

It seems instead I want to make 3 separate queries, in sequence (first to the table **posts**, then to **comments**, then to **replies**)

How do I do this?

---

Comment: Your output requirement is slightly confusing. Are you wanting JSON?

Comment: JSON, or any other type that makes sense. Maybe there is another way to do this without nesting. I simply want the results returned in some smart way, in a single database call

Comment: Nesting as a JSON object does make sense here however I am not familiar enough with postgreSQL's JSON functions to do you any justice here.

Comment: IMO, you do not need to build a JSON if that is not what you want. You should definitely provide your schema description because with just the name of your tables and nothing else, it is impossible to answer. For one, I find it strange to have separate `comments` and`replies` tables. In this situation, I would have created only `comments` with an extra column to store if a comment was a reply to another (`FOREIGN KEY` linking back to the same table).

Comment: @Atmo I included my schema description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “highly redundant” join result is normally the best way, because it is the natural thing in a relational database. Relational databases aim at avoiding redundancy in data storage, but not in query output. Avoiding that redundancy comes at an extra cost: you have to aggregate the data on the server side, and the client probably has to unpack the nested JSON data again.

Here is some sample code that demonstrates how you could aggregate the results:

```
SELECT postid, post_text,
       jsonb_agg(
          jsonb_build_object(
             'commentid', commentid,
             'comment_text', comment_text,
             'replies', replies
          )
       ) AS comments
FROM (SELECT postid, post_text, commentid, comment_text,
             jsonb_agg(
                jsonb_build_object(
                   'replyid', replyid,
                   'reply_text', reply_text
                )
             ) AS replies
      FROM /* your join */
      GROUP BY postid, post_text, commentid, comment_text) AS q
GROUP BY postid, post_text;
```

Comment: Post text can get extremely large (10000+ characters), and I expect to load possibly hundreds of comments and replies. Does this change anything?

Comment: It will make the effects I am talking about worse. Just look at my statement: does that look like it is simple and fast?

Comment: Also, your response is incomplete. Could you please fill in the /* your join */ part?

Comment: I decided to leave that as an exercise to the reader. I try to provide a helpful answer, but I don't feel like undergoing the mechanical work of spelling out the table names and join conditions.

Comment: /* your join */ is a join between what and what? There's no way I'm marking this as the right answer, its not even an answer...

Comment: It would be helpful, but it is incomplete... :(

Comment: The `/* your join */` in my answer refers to the table you show in your question under "For instance, fetching the data from two different replies will give". But I see that you got another answer that you like better. Great!

Comment: I figured out the join. It would have helped if you just said something like 'create a table with all the information in it'... I have another question - is this approach terrible practice, or is it ok to use in prod?

Comment: As I said, I think it is bad practice. Transferring the redundant data in a tabular result is usually simpler and performs better.

Comment: For the tabular result - my confusion is I have a 10,000+ character post, which will be shown redundantly possibly hundreds of times (since there are hundreds of replies possible). Would it be better to do two calls, one for the post, and another for comments/replies? Thanks

Comment: That may be useful, if the post has many attributes. Make sure that you get all comments with a single query though, not one per comment.

Answer (score 1):

The redundant data stems from a cross join of a post's comments and replies. I.e. for each post you join each comment with each reply. Comment 78 does neither relate to reply 14 nor to reply 15, but merely to the same post.

The typical approach to select the data would hence be three queries:

```
select * from posts;
select * from comments;
select * from replies;
```

You can also reduce this to two queries and join the posts table to the comments query, the replies query, or both. This again, will lead to selecting redundant data, but may ease data handling in your app.

If you want to avoid joins, but must avoid database round trips, you can glue query results together:

```
select *
from
(
  select postid as id, postid, 'post' as type, post_text as text from posts
    union all
  select commentid as id, postid, 'comment' as type, comment_text as text from comments
    union all
  select replyid as id, postid, 'reply' as type, reply_text as text from replies
) glued
order by postid, type, id;
```

At last you can create JSON in your DBMS. Again, don't cross join comments with replies, but join the aggregated comments object and the aggregated replies object to the post.

```
select p.postid, p.post_text, c.comments, r.replies
from posts p
left join
(
  select
    postid,
    jsonb_object_agg(jsonb_build_object('commentid', commentid, 
                                        'comment_text', comment_text)
                    ) as comments
  from comments
  group by postid
) c on c.postid = p.postid
left join
(
  select
    postid,
    jsonb_object_agg(jsonb_build_object('replyid', replyid, 
                                        'reply_text', reply_text)
                    ) as replies
  from replies
  group by postid
) r on r.postid = p.postid;
```

Comment: Thanks. Do any of these perform better than others / what is best practice? I'm not against querying the database multiple times, as you would "typically" do. But this would require O(number of comments) communications with the database, which seems unreasonable. Combining comments and replies would fix this. But I do not want to store many nested comments (this is not reddit style), and didn't want to allow for this freedom in storage.

Comment: Sorry I cannot answer this. It really depends on the app and the database connection, how many posts you access, whether you must display all comments and replies right away, how the users interact with your app ... I'd probably go with separate queries as long as there are no performance issues.

Comment: I'm getting a 'too many connections to database' error when using separate queries. I suppose this counts as a performance error..

Answer (score 1):

Your idea to store things in JSON is a good one if you have something to parse it down the line.

As an alternative to the previous answers that involve JSON, you can also get a normal SQL result set (table definition and sample data are below the query):

```
WITH MyFilter(postid) AS (
VALUES (1),(2) /* rest of your filter */
)
SELECT 'Post' AS PublicationType, postid, NULL AS CommentID, NULL As ReplyToID, post_text
FROM Posts
WHERE postID IN (SELECT postid from MyFilter)
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE ReplyToID WHEN NULL THEN 'Comment' ELSE 'Reply' END, postid, commentid, replyToID, comment_text
FROM Comments
WHERE postid IN (SELECT postid from MyFilter)
ORDER BY postid, CommentID NULLS FIRST, ReplyToID NULLS FIRST
```

Note: the `PublicationType` column was added for the sake of clarity. You can alternatively inspect `CommentID` and `ReplyToId` and see what is null to determine the type of publication.

This should leave you with very little, if any, redundant data to transfer back to the SQL client.

---

This approach with `UNION ALL` will work with 3 tables too (you only have to add 1 `UNION ALL`) but in your case, I would rather go with a 2-table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
postid SERIAL primary key,
post_text text NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE comments (
commentid SERIAL primary key,
ReplyToID INTEGER NULL REFERENCES Comments(CommentID) /* ON DELETE CASCADE? */,
postid INTEGER NOT NULL references posts(postid) /* ON DELETE CASCADE? */,
comment_text Text NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO posts(post_text) VALUES ('Post 1'),('Post 2'),('Post 3');
INSERT INTO Comments(postid, comment_text) VALUES (1, 'Comment 1.1'), (1, 'Comment 1.2'), (2, 'Comment 2.1');
INSERT INTO Comments(replytoId, postid, comment_text) VALUES (1, 1, 'Reply to comment 1.1'), (3, 2, 'Reply to comment 2.1');
```

This makes 1 fewer table and allows to have level 2 replies (replies to replies), or more, rather than just replies to comments. A recursive query (there are plenty of samples of that on SO) can make it so a reply can always be linked back to the original comment if you want.

---

**Edit**: I noticed your comment just a bit late. Of course, no matter what solution you take, there is no need to execute a request to get the replies to each and every comment.

Even with 3 tables, even without JSON, the query to get all the replies for all the comments at once is:

```
SELECT *
FROM replies
WHERE commentid IN (
    SELECT commentid
    FROM comments
    WHERE postid IN (
        /* List your post ids here or nest another SELECT postid FROM posts WHERE ... */
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll consider going with that schema. I was just holding off since I didn't want to worry about (doubly or more) nested comments. This was very helpful.

Comment: I had not seen your previous comment before writing my answer. What does "*But this would require O(number of comments) communications with the database, which seems unreasonable*" mean? I'm afraid to interpret it as "I need to execute 1 query for each and every comment".

Comment: Yes, I meant "I need to execute 1 query for each and every comment"

Comment: /What if I wanted to get the first 2 replies to every comment?

Comment: Ohhh so that is your real question! the thing that explains why you thought you needed to execute 1 query per comment. Your schema has no column to identify what reply comes first though, so I cannot answer. You have to look for window functions. The easiest way to get you started is for you to read the corresponding [help page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), especially the **2nd example from the bottom**. List of window functions is [there](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)

Comment: Thanks for all the advice! I'll be sorting on the `created_at` column, which I didn't include. Equivalently, I think one can sort by `postid` for purposes of an example.

Comment: Sorting by `post_id` (assumring values are generated by a sequence) works ... until it doesn't. **Never let a `PRIMARY KEY` generated by a sequence carry any functional meaning**: it is supposed to be used to uniquely identify records for `UPDATE` and `DELETE` commands, `FOREIGN KEY`s and **nothing else**. For instance, you have no guarantee, especially as you update your code in the future, to never run in a situation where sequence values are generated when a reply starts being edited but `created_date` correspond to the validation; which means the 2 fields will not be in the same order.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this with either a window function, or with json aggregate? The other answers about jsons are both incorrect/incomplete.